# Excessive SignalR service costs with server side blazor?

Tags: blazor, signalr, stability

We have a Line of Business app serving ~450 users - mostly with the app open most of the day.
We are running 3 instances of P3V3 app service during core business hours and 2 instances out of hours.

We're seeing 20M messages per day and our Azure SignalR Service costs are double the app service cost.

When we use websockets, our users complain about intermittent SignalR circuit drop outs.

We are not using SignalR for anything other than blazor.

We have raised the issue with MS but they're not really interested.

So far we have found no way to save costs on SignalR - no reservations and you have no control over the messages blazor is sending.

Our app is using Styncfusion blazor components.
Have others experienced similar issues or are we doing something wrong?

Comment: _"Our app is using Styncfusion blazor components."_ <-- There's your problem (well... _probably_ your problem): Component vendors always focus on packing the most features and functionality into their toolkits without concern about bloat or optimizing the important fundamentals because they're invariably always deployed to internal corporate LANs where having a ~20MB `.js` file isn't considered anywhere near as much of a problem as it is on the public Internet.

Comment: Also, Blazor is not intended for use on the public web [beause it's a heavyweight](https://medium.com/young-coder/is-blazor-the-future-or-just-another-walled-garden-441842cc249d) - even the server-side version (well, _especially_ the server-side version because it makes your web-servers stateful...).

Comment: _"you have no control over the messages blazor is sending."_ - technically, you can have full control, but it means having to clone and maintain your own fork of Blazor that you'll customize to be more efficient.

Comment: 20M messages, 450 users, 8 hour day, ~1.5 messages per second per user - seems a little high if they are idle, but not too unreasonable for an application that is designed to maintain a stateful connection. Maybe a rethink about the design is what is needed? Can any parts be made razor pages instead? can users be logged out when idle?